# Ignoring the field in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with jasper-reports 4.5.0.I have a jrxml file which has 4 fields.I am using the same jrxml file for different different entity classes.One of my entity class has only three fields.In that case it is giving no such method exception.My doubt is for the entity class which is having the three fields then the jrxml has to use only three fields and ignores the fourth field.How can i do that.Any idea on this to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible using purely *JasperReports*, but I've accomplished it with *DynamicJasper*. It uses JasperReports in the background but allows you to create reports dynamically.